# Rhapsody reverse engineering error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, rhapsody

I am using Rational Rhapsody Developer for C# (Rhapsody 8.1) and trying to reverse engineer a C# program that was developed using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. I get an error from Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell, saying "Invalid License Data. Reinstall is required." My Visual Studio 2015 is working fine, and I don't really want to reinstall it. Do I need to reinstall Rhapsody, perhaps, or is there some configuration setting I can change?

Comment: Unsure if you know about this, but I would recommend to ask this question on the specific [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) site. Don't forget to read their [help center](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help) as they have a different format than on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that Rhapsody 8.1.1 does not support reverse engineering with Visual Studio 2015. It does support reverse engineering with Visual Studio 2008 SP1, Visual Studio 2010, and Visual Studio 2012.